# Undefined variable in welcome.blade

Tags: laravel-5.5

ItemsController has below code

```
public function index()
{
    $items = Item::all();
    return view('welcome' , ['items' => $items]);
}
```

The model name is Item

In welcome.blade i am calling it like this

```
       @foreach($items as $item)
        <li class="list-group-item"><a href="/{{$item->id}}">{{$item->title}}</a></li>
        @endforeach
```

but it gives "Undefined variable: items (View: ..... welcome.blade.php)"

Also i want to know, how will i get and show a single row from database. and how i will get and show many rows. Being new to laravel; things are confusing me a lot.

Comment: I suggest you add `dd($items)` after `$items = Item::all();` to make sure that `$items` is set.

Comment: I added dd($items) but still getting same error